# ASP.Net MVC 5 OAuth2 Facebook Claims are not persisted. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, claims

I just created a new MVC application to learn something about OAuth2. To get started I registered as a developer with Facebook and enabled the Facebook Identity Provider in my application:

### Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
           appId: "something",
           appSecret: "secret");
```

Authentication worked straight out of the box but I wondered if my User property of my Homecontroller had any Facebook related information. It had not and I wondered why. I had a look at the Katana/Owin sources how the Facebook provider is implemented and found a place where custom claims are being set:

### FacebookAuthenticationHandler.cs

```
context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:facebook:name", context.Name, XmlSchemaString, Options.AuthenticationType));
```

But when I reach my Controller and check the Identity's Claims property there are none of these custom claims once set by the Owin provider. When I check the 
database (AspNetUserClaims table) I find that completely deserted.

Is there a reason why claims are not persisted to the db? Is the db even a good place to store these claims (at least there is a table)? Do I have to configure anything in my application to get the claims presisted? Or is there another point where I can keep the claims to be alive for the whole user session?

Answer (score 2):

Allright, dove a bit deeper into Owin and came to the conclusion that the Authentication Providers are part of an Owin middleware construct which runs independently in a pipeline and does not affect the applications principal directly. There is an action in the AccountController named *ExternalLoginCallback* which is called when the whole auth aria is finished. It gets an *ExternalLoginInfo* object which holds all my claims and constructs an *ApplicationUser* which acts as the official application user. It has a Claims property but that one is not automatically populated with my claims from the ExternalLoginInfo and I guess the reason is that claims could change with every login. So in my case I would better delete all old old claims before I add the new to my user. Since this is custom I have to provide that somehow by myself. Since this data is very volatile I keep that in Session for now.

Any comments on that issue are warmly welcome.

Comment: Curious how you addressed this.  I'm dealing with the same issue.  Everything that I want are in the original claims however they don't carry over.